# whats the difference between type() and print(type())

Tags: python

Im new to coding and I don't understand the difference between if I put type() and if I put print(type()) in the program because I get the same thing that is <class 'str'>. Can you add something if you type print(type()) or is there really no difference?

Comment: The interactive shell always implicitly prints the last result. That is not so in an actual program which you run outside the shell.

Answer (score 2):

In the Python REPL, it's hard to tell the difference:

```py
>>> type('poo')
<class 'str'>
>>> print(type('poo'))
<class 'str'>
```

However, it's easy to see indirectly:

```py
>>> s = type('poo')
>>> s
<class 'str'>
>>> s = print(type('poo'))
<class 'str'>
>>> s
None
```

In other words, you are being fooled by the behavior of the REPL to print results immediately. In an actual Python program, this is not true at all, and more similar to the second example above.